# Serialize a MongoRecord using Lift

Tags: json, scala, serialization, mongodb, lift

I'm having trouble building a restful service with Lift. All I want to do at this point is serialize a MongoRecord to JSON. Here is my model:

```
class Team extends MongoRecord[Team] with MongoId[Team] {
  def meta = Team

  object name extends StringField(this, 100)
  object slug extends StringField(this, 100)
}

object Team extends Team with MongoMetaRecord[Team] {
  def all = Team orderAsc (_.slug) fetch()

  def apply(in: JValue): Box[Team] = Helpers.tryo{in.extract[Team]}

  def unapply(in: String): Option[Team] = Team where (_.slug eqs in) get()

  implicit def toJson(team: Team): JValue =
    Extraction.decompose(team)

  implicit def toJson(teams: Seq[Team]): JValue =
    Extraction.decompose(teams)
}
```

And here is my implementation of RestHelper:

```
object TeamRestService extends RestHelper {
  serve( "api" / "teams" prefix {
    case Nil JsonGet _ => Team.all: JValue

    case Team(team) :: Nil JsonGet _ => team: JValue
  })
}
```

Using `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/teams` I get `[{}, {}]`, and with `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/teams/team-1` I get {}. If I put a print statement in the `TeamRestService` before returning either the single team or the list of teams, I can clearly see that all of the data has been set on the Team instances. For some reason, the serialization is just returning empty objects. What do I need to do to make my Team instances serialize properly? Do I need to make a custom format or use some kind of TypeHint? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I was stupid. `Extraction.decompose` only works with case classes. `MongoRecord` has a method `asJValue`. Using that in the implicit defs solved the issue.

```
implicit def toJson(team: Team): JValue = team.asJValue

implicit def toJson(teams: Seq[Team]): JValue = teams map { _.asJValue }
```

Comment: ```teams map ( _.asJValue )``` gives you a ```Seq[JValue]``` thus you would want ```JArray(teams map ( _.asJValue ))```